when the program is deployed, modifying the data structure
I really want to know what will happen if after deploying the program, I need to upgrade it and change some fields in the struct, such as the following situations.
The struct before my upgrade is like this.
#[account(zero_copy)]
pub struct ProtocolConfig {
    pub protocol_fee_rate: u32,
    pub whitelist_protocol_fee_rate: u32,
    pub whitelist_uuid: [[u8; 24]; WHITE_PUBKEY_SIZE_USIZE],
    pub future_use: [u8; 128], //for future use
}

I think there won't be any issues if the upgraded struct becomes like this (using the for_feature_use field,), but I'm not completely sure.I want to know a definite answer
#[account(zero_copy)]
pub struct ProtocolConfig {
    pub protocol_fee_rate: u32,
    pub whitelist_protocol_fee_rate: u32,
    pub whitelist_uuid: [[u8; 24]; WHITE_PUBKEY_SIZE_USIZE],
    pub new_use:Pubkey, //new field
    pub future_use: [u8; 96], //sub 32 byte
}

Additionally,If i directly add a new byte to the current data structure without using the for_feature_use field, what will happen? Will the accounts created through PDA become invalid?like this
#[account(zero_copy)]
pub struct ProtocolConfig {
    pub protocol_fee_rate: u32,
    pub whitelist_protocol_fee_rate: u32,
    pub whitelist_uuid: [[u8; 24]; WHITE_PUBKEY_SIZE_USIZE],
    pub future_use: [u8; 128], //didnt sub 32 byte
    pub new_use:Pubkey, //just add a new filed(32byte)
}


In the first case, you'll be fine, but be sure to handle the situation where the new_use field is all zeroes, ie. the default value.
In the second case, if you don't realloc the account for the new field, it will immediately fail deserialization when your program tries to use it. So you'll need to use realloc on the account.
